# .htaccess rule error for redirecting from a homepage form submit

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a top level domain that has a form in it, when I submit the form I get the error that it's no found (it's looking for it in the wrong place.)

the original locations of the index is here: `www.tld.com/tld/src/index.html`
the php file that handles the form into the DB is here: `www.tld.com/tld/lib/phpfile.php`
I am using this .htaccess rule to send my homepage to www.tld.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tld/src/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /tld/src/$1 [L]
```

**Obviously, the redirection is an error:** `The requested URL /tld/src/lib/phpfile.php was not found on this server.` since the file exists in `www.tld.com/tld/lib/phpfile.php`

> My current and only settings except for the above are:

```
Options All -Indexes


 <Files .htaccess>
  deny from all  
 </Files>
```

> And that's it.

I am new to .htaccess apache rulesets and I have no idea how to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your exception condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tld/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(src|lib)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) src/$1 [L]
```

Above condition will skip any request that starts with `/tld/lib/` or `/tld/src/` thus allowing your form to be routed to correct php file in `/tld/lib/` directory.

Comment: it is looking for the php in tld/src/lib/, instead of just tld/lib/

Comment: everything works fine on my localhost and the form is directing properly to lib/phpfile.php, the error only started with the htaccess file written unproperly by me.  Your change in that line has not had any effect and providing the exact same error.

Comment: my form action is: `action="/tld/lib/phpfile.php"` just as you suggested, the error I get is: Not Found
`The requested URL /tld/src/tld/lib/phpfile.php was not found on this server.`
With my original 'action="../lib/phpfile.php" ` I got: `The requested URL /tld/src/lib/phpfile.php` was not found on this server. I did exactly as you advised, please try to amend.

Comment: I've written my other rules (re-edit in question). There is nothing else and since i'm working with cpanel in my centos vps, it's set like this:

 public_html>tld>.htaccess file is here